# How to convert C++ class/struct to a primitive/different type/class/struct?

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading, class-design

I have the following class CppProperty class that holds value:

```
template<typename TT>
class CppProperty
{
    TT val;
public:
    CppProperty(void)
    {
    }

    CppProperty(TT aval) : val(aval)
    {
    }

    CppProperty(const CppProperty & rhs)
    {
        this->val = rhs.val;
    }

    virtual ~CppProperty(void)
    {
    }

    TT operator=(TT aval)
    {
        this->val = aval;
        return this->val;
    }

    friend TT operator++(CppProperty & rhs);
    friend TT operator--(CppProperty & rhs);
    friend TT operator++(CppProperty & rhs, int);
    friend TT operator--(CppProperty & rhs, int);

    //template<typename RR>
    //friend RR operator=(RR & lhs, const CppProperty & rhs);
    //friend int & operator=(int & lhs, const CppProperty & rhs);
    //int reinterpret_cast<int>(const CppProperty & rhs);
};
```

I want to do assignment like this:

```
CppProperty<char> myproperty(10);
myproperty++;
int count = myproperty;
```

How this can be done? I can't override the operator=. Any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'd need a conversion operator:

```
operator const TT&(void) const
{
    return val;
}


operator TT&(void)
{
    return val;
}
```

There is a brief tutorial on conversion operators [here](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/910-overloading-typecasts/). In short, when the compiler tries to convert a type, it will first look at the right-hand side for an operator that will convert it to the desired type. What we are doing is saying "Whatever `TT` is, this class can be converted to it".

If no operators are found, it looks to see if the left-hand side can be constructed from the right-hand side, and so on. (Until, if it cannot find a conversion, it emits an error.)

---

You can remove your explicitly defined default constructor if you declare your other constructor like this:

```
// If not specified, construct with default-constructed type.
CppProperty(TT aval = TT()) : val(aval)
{
}
```

Comment: Thanks GMan! Looks cool! Let me try and get back to you in a short while ;)

Comment: No problem, make sure your `const`'s are in the correct location, I had them backwards in the first post.

Comment: Can you please add some explanation for what does operator TT&() does? I didn't get how it works.

Comment: Indeed. Did you mean you didn't understand it before or until now?

Comment: I knew about the conversion operators..but didn't think that it can be used with templates..I thought I should always hardcode the class name in the operator.

Comment: Ah, I see. Yup any type will do, even if it's a template.

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide `operator int()` to your class to allow the implicit conversion to int.

Comment: Hi Naveen! Thanks for quick reply. Then how to convert to different classes/datatypes using operators?

Answer (score 1):

You may overload a typecast:

http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/910-overloading-typecasts/

Comment: Hi shaleo! Thanks for your help. I've managed to get things done using GMan's advice. I'm looking into yours now :)